# How to exchange commands in c# and python using tcp server

Tags: c#, python, tcpclient

I am making c# windows forms that will be sending commands to a python program. I want the windows form to be able to excute commands. Like typing something in the textbox and have a print button so when we press is it will excute the print command in the python console.

I want the python to be the host and the c# to be the client.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I recommend trying it first and then coming back to us if you encounter any problems. Start by reading about TCP in each language.

Comment: I made the server but I had no idea how to exhange the commands.

Comment: What do you mean "exchange the commands"? TCP is a pipe that you send bytes down. How you format those bytes is up to you. Just remember that what you receive isn't formatted to your idea of a "command", so you need to also prefix the data with a length to indicate how long the message is.